# How to make unity unresponsive?

Tags: unity, window-manager, shortcut-keys

Recently I wanted to test a keyboard shortcut, which is supposed to kill X server (hence very useful when you have a crash). That shortcut is not dependent on any particular window manager (like `lxde`, `unity`, `kwin` etc). So, it must work, even when you have unresponsive (to keybings) window manager (*as opposed to `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`Backspace` which kills the session, and bring you a login screen*).

That's why I interested to make my window manager(unity) unresponsive. Is past, it was very easy. Opening a terminal, typing `unity --replace` and then force close the terminal, was the simplest procedure. But unfortunately, This is not true in Ubuntu 12.04, (*they make it very robust*) Because whenever I kill the terminal, Unity automagically restart itself.

I also tried `compiz --replace` but wasn't successful.

My question is: How can I make Unity unresponsive to any keyboard shortcuts (*of it's keybindings*) while I am in Unity session, so that I can test the global shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/154439/61218) from Eliah Kagan was great, But I think, I can answer now from my experience in less technical words.

### There are two ways (*as revealed to me*) to test that keyboard shortcut:

- Open a terminal and type `unity` or `unity --replace` (*both are same*) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  #### If you want a *crash* like look of Unity

  - While you are on the terminal, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the unity will be stopped immediately.
  - Then try your global shortcut.

  #### If you want a decent look of Unity (Freeze)

  - While you are on the terminal, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (*as suggested by @Eliah Kagan*), the unity will be suspended immediately. Everything will be *freezed*, except the cursor.
  - Then try your global shortcut.

---

#### keyboard shortcut to kill X:

That particular keyboard shortcut was : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> . You will need this, if you wanted to try.

---

Thanks to [@Mahesh](https://askubuntu.com/users/45659/mahesh), for revealing that shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Running `unity --replace` and then closing the Terminal doesn't make `unity` unresponsive in any version of Ubuntu. It causes `unity` to *not be running altogether*.

It seems that in 12.04, `unity` will (usually) then restart by itself; in previous versions, it generally won't.

If you actually need to make `unity` unresponsive, you'll have to use a different technique. Perhaps you could edit your question to elaborate about your specific needs.

A generic way to make a program stop responding is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in its controlling terminal. So if you run `unity --replace` in a Terminal window (or virtual console), you can do that, and it will *stop*, without *terminating*.

You can also do [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signals) manually with [SIGSTOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP) and [SIGCONT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCONT) (that is, `kill -STOP PID` and `kill -CONT PID`, where **`PID`** is the process ID of the process you want to make unresponsive). But having an associated terminal for the process in which you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is better because then the shell running in that terminal will let you use job control on the process. That is, it will be listed with `jobs`, and you can make it respond again with either `bg` or `fg`. See the [official `bash` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) for more information.